# Unity custom shader turning pink

Tags: unity, shaders

I'm quite new to writing custom shaders. Wanted to try it out by creating a sand-standard surface shader. A problem that occurred was when I finished writing my custom shader in Unity, the material that was based on the custom shader returned pink. Is there a way to fix the custom shader, or does it mean the material no longer works?
Here's what I've written so far; any feedback would be great.

```
Shader "Custom/Sand"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
        _MainNormal("MainNormal", 2D) = "bump" {}

        //[Header(Sand info)]
        _SandTexture("Sand texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _SandNormal("Sand normal", 2D) = "bump" {}
        _SandColor("Sand color", color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _SandDirection("Sand direction", Vector) = (0,1,0)
        _SandLevel("Sand level", Range(-1,1)) = 0
        _SandGlossiness("Sand glossiness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _SandMetallic("Sand Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        CGPROGRAM
        // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

        // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
        #pragma target 3.0
      /*  #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
      */
        sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct Input{
            float2 uv_MainTex;
            float2 uv_MainNormal;
            float2 uv_SandNormal;
            float2 uv_SandTexture;
            float3 worldNormal;
            INTERNAL_DATA
        };

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _Color;
        sampler2D _MainNormal;

        sampler2D _SandTexture;
        sampler2D _SandNormal;
        fixed4 _SandColor;
        float4 _SandDirection;
        float _SandLevel;
        float _SandGlossiness;
        float _SandMetallic;

        // Add instancing support for this shader. You need to check 'Enable Instancing' on materials that use the shader.
        // See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html for more information about instancing.
        // #pragma instancing_options assumeuniformscaling
        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
            // put more per-instance properties here
        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
        {
            //Color and normals of the main textures
            fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
            float3 normals = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_MainNormal, IN.uv_MainNormal));
            //Color and normals sand texture
            fixed4 SandColor = tex2D(_SandTexture, IN.uv_SandTexture) * _SandColor;
            float3 SandNormals = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_SandNormal, IN.uv_SandNormal));

            half SandDot = step(_SandLevel, dot(WorldNormalVector(IN, normals), normalize(_SandDirection)));

            o.Normal = lerp(normals, SandNormals, SandDot);
            // Albedo comes from a texture tinted by color
            o.Albedo = lerp(c.rgb, SandColor, SandDot);
            // Metallic and smoothness come from slider variables
            o.Metallic = lerp(_Metallic,_SandMetallic,SandDot);
            o.Smoothness = lerp(_Glossiness,_SandGlossiness, SandDot);
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: A material turning pink usually means that the shader can't be loaded. Probably due to some compilation error. Is there anything suspicious in the console?

Comment: Are you on a built in renderer or SRP? (URP/HDRP)

Comment: @WeckarE. Im on a built in renderer URP

Comment: @Philipp No issues or anything suspicious has appeared

Comment: @Pantra The "built-in renderer" and the URP ("Universal Render Pipeline") are two different things. https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.3/Documentation/Manual/render-pipelines-overview.html